# Permissions for the application with messages

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I have an application that uses Firebase Realtime as a database.

The user follows certain collections and when something appears, he receives a notification on the phone

At the moment notification is coming but the user doesn't know it. He must check it manually

What permissions should I give in the application to be:

- sound
- vibration
- lock screen notification
- counter next to the app icon
- diode
- high importance

In current situation I use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it seems to work without asking permission on android?

[From here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#ios---requesting-permissions)

"On Android, you do not need to request user permission. This method can still be called on Android devices; however, and will always resolve successfully."

Or I found some old code on website they setting like this, but I'm not sure if it works in latest version:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```